# Migrate Existing Data Into VARRAY Types

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the following VARRAY type defined in my db schema:

```
create or replace type STRING_VECTOR is varray(10) of varchar2(50);
```

I also have the following Employee database table

```
first name| last name| salary
'John'    | 'Doe'    | 10.00
```

Note that the salary column is a NUMBER(38,14).

What I would like to do is add a fourth column that is of my STRING_VECTOR type.  I would like to populate my string vector with String values for each record like so:

```
first name| last name| salary| data
'John'    | 'Doe'    | 10.00 | ['John', 'Doe', '10.00']
```

Could someone give me some pointers as to whether PL/SQL can be written to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not hard at all, take a look:

```
CREATE TABLE my_emp_test (
  first_name VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name VARCHAR2(20),
  salary NUMBER(38, 14)
);

INSERT INTO my_emp_test VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 10.00);

COMMIT;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE string_vector IS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(50);

ALTER TABLE my_emp_test ADD data string_vector;

UPDATE my_emp_test
  SET data = string_vector(first_name, last_name, TO_CHAR(salary))
;

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM my_emp_test;
```

```
FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                SALARY DATA                               
-------------------- -------------------- ---------- ------------------------------------
John                 Doe                          10 HR.STRING_VECTOR('John','Doe','10')
```

You wrote that you wanted PL/SQL, but it can be done in pure SQL as you can see, is that going to work for you?

Comment: Awesome!  At first glance it looks promising.  I'll give it a shot.  I didn't realize I could inline the vector creation in an update statement.